# Ruby Geocoder not updating latitude/longitude Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my code:

```
  after_validation :check_geo

  geocoded_by :gmaps4rails_address

  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{street}, #{city}, #{region}, #{postal_code}, #{country}"
  end

  def check_geo
    unless self.latitude
      :geocode
    end
  end
```

This used to work fine. I have confirmed that check_geo is running but it seems to be having no effect. Could this be another strong parameters issue?

Comment: I don't know how this ever worked, to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `:geocode` with `geocode`.

`:geocode` is a symbol, it doesnt do anything, `geocode` will actually trigger the method

Comment: This answer turned up in the low-quality queue. I don't speak ruby, so maybe it's obvious, but perhaps you could add a bit more explanation.